# Can you do binary file input and out in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, file, actionscript, binary, adobe

I want to write a logging system to log errors but I want the format of the file to be binary. Can you write and/or read binary files in Flex 4? (actionscript to be more precise)

Comment: before you embark on this, look at Log4j and it's flex counterparts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can write binary files using the ByteArray class, and save them using the FileReference class (you need to target FP10).

For example, to write an XML file to binary, you simply do:

```
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
ba.writeUTFBytes( myXML ); // myXML is an XML object
ba.compress(); // this will compress the ByteArray, saving you a ton in size
```

To save it, you run it through the FileReference API:

```
var file:FileReference = new FileReference;
file.save( ba, "myXML.xml" );
```

The only drawback with this is that FileReference.save() has to be called from a user action (mouse click/keyboard press). Going through the FileStream class in AIR gives you more options. FileReference can also be used to upload files to the server. Check out the docs to get more of an idea: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html

Alternatively, you can save your ByteArray info through a SharedObject (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) without too much hassle, or do it as Flextras suggested and run it through a server script.

ByteArray docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html

Comment: +! for having a more complete answer than I.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a Flex web based app has very limited ability to write or read files that are local to a machine.  If you're using AIR you can use the [File API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) and the [FileStream API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html).  It should be possible to read/write binary files with that.

If you're building a web based app; then you can send data to the server, and let that save files.  I believe most application servers should support reading and writing of binary files.